# How to remove all the anchor tags from content using PHP

Tags: php, rss

I'm extracting content from an RSS feed, but it comes with anchor `<a>` tags which I need to remove.

For this I tried `strip_tags` but it removed all HTML tags including `<img>`.

Then I tried:

```
$content = preg_replace("/<a[^>]\+>|<a>|<\/a>/i", "", $content);
```

But it did not work for me 100%.

Then I tried DOM:

```
$xml = new DOMDocument(); 
$xml->loadHTML($content); 
$links = $xml->getElementsByTagName('a');
```

But I don't know how to extract the content without the `<a>` tags.

Comment: As @Leri said, strip_tags is simplest for this job, if you can list all tags allowed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When parsing rss it's good idea to strip all tags and maintain those that are used for text formatting (`<p>`, `<b>`, `<i>`, etc.). So you need to pass second parameter to [`strip_tags`](https://www.php.net/strip_tags).

> [Docs:](https://www.php.net/strip_tags)
>
> **allowable_tags**
>
> You can use the optional second parameter to specify tags which should **not** be stripped.

For example:

```
echo strip_tags($contentFromRSS, '<p><div><i><b><u>');
```

[Sample](http://ideone.com/YS341J)

Comment: Then what about the <img> one ?

Comment: @vs7 If you want to remain `<img>` tag, add it to the second parameter. E.g., `'<p><div><i><b><u><img>'`

Answer (score 1):

Remove `<a>` element while keeping inner value.

```
<?php

$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML('<div><a href="#">text</a></div>');

foreach ($doc->getElementsByTagName('a') as $e)
{
  $e->parentNode->nodeValue = $e->nodeValue;
}

echo $doc->saveHTML(); # <div>text</div>
```

Remove `<a>` entirely.

```
<?php

$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML('<div><a href="#">text</a></div>');

foreach ($doc->getElementsByTagName('a') as $e)
{
  $e->parentNode->removeChild($e);
}

echo $doc->saveHTML(); # <div></div>
```

**P.S.** Without *exact* HTML it's hard to make a "working" example. Even if my code doesn't work out of the box, you should try to fix it yourself and ditch the *gimme teh codez! ASAP* attitude as shown in chat.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the DOM function to modify the HTML or an XSLT to transform it. You need to be aware that loadHtml() will fix the HTML-DOM and add  and  elements. To get the fixed fragment, you will have to save each child of .

### With DOM functions

```
$html = <<<'HTML'
  <a href="http://foo.tld">TEST</a>
HTML;

$dom = new DOMDocument(); 
$dom->loadHTML($html); 

foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('a') as $node) {
  $textNode = $dom->createTextNode($node->nodeValue);
  $node->parentNode->replaceChild($textNode, $node);
}

$fragment = '';
foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('body')->item(0)->childNodes as $node) {
  $fragment .= $dom->saveHtml($node);
}

var_dump($fragment);
```

### XSLT

XSLT is a language designed to transform the DOM. Using it adds some bootstrap, but if you add more rules, it will be the better way.

```
$html = <<<'HTML'
  <a href="http://foo.tld">TEST</a>
HTML;

$xsl = <<<'XSL'
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet
  version="1.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="a">
  <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>

<!-- pass through for unknown tags in the xml tree -->
<xsl:template match="*">
  <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
    <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
XSL;

$dom = new DOMDocument(); 
$dom->loadHTML($html); 

$xslDom =  new DOMDocument();
$xslDom->loadXml($xsl);

$xsltProc = new XsltProcessor();
$xsltProc->importStylesheet($xslDom);

$result = $xsltProc->transformToDoc($dom);

$fragment = '';
foreach ($result->getElementsByTagName('body')->item(0)->childNodes as $node) {
  $fragment .= $result->saveHtml($node);
}
var_dump($fragment);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$xml = new DOMDocument(); 
$xml->loadHTML($html); 

$links = $xml->getElementsByTagName('a');

//Loop through each <a> tags and replace them by their text content    
for ($i = $links->length - 1; $i >= 0; $i--) {
    $linkNode = $links->item($i);
    $lnkText = $linkNode->textContent;
    $newTxtNode = $xml->createTextNode($lnkText);
    $linkNode->parentNode->replaceChild($newTxtNode, $linkNode);
}
```